Docker container "не видит" некоторые внешние ресурсы
На моей рабочей машине с Windows 10 установлен Docker-Desktop с WSL2 прослойкой Ubuntu 20.04
Я запускаю контейнер docker run -it --rm -p 80:80 nginx /bin/bash - использую для примера
И в нем хочу обратиться к серверу 192.168.10.47, но docker его не видит. Также он не видит другие сервера типа 192.168.x.x, но спокойно пингует 10.30.x.x и любые другие внешние ресурсы, например google.com и yandex.ru.
При этом как с WSL, так и с локальной машины, ping успешно проходит.
Пожалуйста подскажите в какую сторону копать.
Что я пытался сделать:

Использовал host
docker run -it --rm --net=host -p 80:80 nginx /bin/bash - не помогло
Выполнил переустановку WSL
К данному решению пришел из-за того, что на соседнем ПК, где установлены те же версии программ, все успешно работает. Однако переустановка не помогла.

